# My HTC Desire Z read messages showing up unread

Tags: sms

I am starting to have some prolems with my Desire Z and was wondering if anyone knew how to help me. It is starting to show that I have an unread text message, but when I click on that contact, there isn't. So I tried to delete the message thread and then it just keeps loading and loading (all night even!) so i was forced to restart my phone in order to send any other texts. Also when I exit out of the message thread, "Sorry! The application Messages (process.com.android.mms) has stopped unexpectedly. Please Try again." With a "Force Close" button, comes up.. It's only doing this with one contact, any other messages I recieve don't stay "unread". And whenever I recieve more messages from that contact, the number of unread messages goes up!

Comment: Maybe backing up your data and clearing the Messaging app's data would help? Have your tried that?

Comment: Try another SMS app, see if it ends up fixing the DB for your SMS's.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with that contact, i would try deleting them from you contact list and putting them in as a fresh, new contact.